# Setting a border for a canvas wrapped in kineticJS

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I just copypasted the code from the tutorial:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-rect-tutorial/

The problem is that the style setting for canvas{} isn't taken in account.

I clearly know where the canvas is and that it SHOULD work because:
        A) I've already done it, but I can't get a working copy of the code
        B) Firebug tells me that there IS a canvas... So why it doesn't work?

My final goal is to distinguish the stage visually (by a border or a proper background color)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, alternatively you can draw a border with background color inside KineticJS by using a Kinetic.Rect to distinguish the stage visually:

```
var border = new Kinetic.Rect({
  width: stage.getWidth(),
  height: stage.getHeight(),
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 4, //Border Size in Pixels
  fill: '#00FF00' //Background Color
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/UDG8e/)

The only tiny issue with this is that you'll get 1 Extra Kinetic Node inside your canvas. If you wanna keep the solution outside the canvas, than style your `#container` to be the same width and height as your stage/canvas, and then wrap the `#container` inside another `<div>` and give that `<div>` the original styling you had on `#container`. Like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="containerWrapper">
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#containerWrapper {
  /*#container's old styles here*/
}

#container {
  width: widthOfStage;
  height: heightOfStage;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  background:#00FF00;
}
```

[2nd example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/GYe2c/)

Comment: The first one is the one I just found out, the second one is a brilliant ider :)